# How to send multiple notifications in FCM in NodeJS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send multiple notifications to specific devices, im triying this for 1-1 comunication :

```
router.post('/send', function(req, res){  
    getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){
        var title = req.body.title;
        var body = req.body.body;
        var token = req.body.token;

        request.post({
            headers:{
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            url:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MYPROJECT/messages:send",
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    "message":{
                        "token": token,
                        "notification":{
                         "body":body,
                         "title":title
                       }
                    }
                 }
            )
        }, function(error, response,body){
            res.end(body);
            console.log(body);
        });
    });
});
```

and it really works. The problem is, i dont know program in NodeJS/JS a lot, the code is from YT tutorial and i want to send multiple messages. Im triying this:

```
router.post('/sendmulticast', function(req, res){
    getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){

        var title = req.body.title;
        var body = req.body.body;
        var token = req.body.token;

        for(var i = 0; i <= token.length; i++){
            request.post({
                headers:{
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                url:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MYPROJECT/messages:send",
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "message":{
                            "token": token[i],
                            "notification":{
                             "body":body,
                             "title":title
                           }
                        }
                     }
                )
            }, function(error, response,body){
                res.end(body);
                console.log(body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but it returns ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END, I suppose that since it is an asynchronous task it is waiting for the server's response.

Im triying to subscribe android users to topic but FCM doesnt register the topic. I'd be very grateful if you could help me with this server-side method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.end(body)` seems to be the problem. Put this outside the loop and it should work. You might consider creating a function to post requests.

Comment: they are different functions, one is /send and another is /sendmulticast. Ok, i'll tryings this.

Comment: yes and res.end belongs to the outer-function and is called multiple times now but only should be called once.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks a lot!, but the sending request never ends, how end it? @Robert

Comment: I dont know how the sending request looks like, but probably it has some sort of end-function too. You can first start and end every sending-request and then end the "outer"-res.

Comment: Thank you, im only call the response function and it finished OK. Really Really thank you.